# C++, getline() cant properly load all characters

Tags: c++, get, ifstream, getline

I have text file filled with characters similar to these:

```
¶§čç†8,ĄyŚ}¦PÜĎY®Všw†inmĘkÚhíU”*Q–­Ö}W"ĄőK=Ć“7ßńĎ_0§ĄŚĆš‰ö¤˝†’?šŕý  
î7ź®xż¶¸tÔuYÖa7Ź+6cE#U+:ç˛ů€°6%·˝Î÷Ľm‹¶ĺ¬‰,Y¤r$Ň“üDGhô‚J°ÜYŽäóa·7¶1Ľľ˝.—
bőľaŇ•Ďűż3«ű4°JT.ń¨kŢ&Ś6ÄmĆŕY0Ż/´~9.źÍéşď®ŁýçľURíOQS ›iJ±bĄB“˝¸&§řőUdüió^˛l˛
\›¨úlu+ĆŃSÔPÖDő±Qf6Ö\yÁ17$ŘĆMńŻß:g’×@ř–äy§_ĺąFsMWÓ‰5@ZÝ±˝BvÓáŻŤ’;F¦jąÔî/ż/Ă
```

And there are nearly hundreds of lines of them. Its basically the same mess you'll get when you open some image in notepad.

My task is to find some hidden words inside that file for example: "apple","car" etc. What I got is this:

```
ifstream buffer;
buffer.open("myFile.txt");

string str1;

while(getline(buffer, str1)){

if(str1.find("apple")!=std::string::npos)
            counter++;

if(str1.find("car")!=std::string::npos)
            counter++;

}
```

It works fine when I open file with "normal" characters but as long as there those unusual characters, getline() have problems with loading whole lines.

I added this line into that cycle:

```
myOutputFile << str1;
```

To make sure if getline is loading all lines properly but in my testing output file was written only +-30 lines from cca 200.. I've tried also get() function but result was same. It seems like there is some character which get/getline cant handle and force it to stop loading next characters/lines.

So my question is: is there any way how to force getline to handle this situation or generally any way how to find specific words among this kind of weird characters ?

Thank you.

---

SOLVED:

I've open that file in binary mode and its working now.

```
buffer.open("myFile.txt", ios::binary);
```

Many thanks to **Cheers and hth. - Alf**

Comment: I suspect that you are encountering embedded nulls.

Comment: Are you sure that "apple" cannot appear twice in one line?

Comment: @Beta It can but exact number is not that important for me right now. I would be still grateful if it could find at least one word. Right now iam at 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Windows a Ctrl Z (ASCII 26) will by convention indicate end-of-text.

To avoid that, open the file as binary.

Or use lower level binary file i/o.

Comment: I thought that I'll avoid it by removing eof from condition in cycle